# Apache POI removing picture from template when setting auto filters on columns

Tags: apache, apache-poi

Using Apache poi 3.7 HSSF package to generate xls file from a template. The template xls has png picture. After calling HSSFSheet.setAutoFilter method the picture is disappearing in the generated xls.

Comment: We'll need more information than this.  Please show your relevant code.  Did you try the latest stable release of POI (3.9)?

Comment: I did not try with apache POI 3.9. Here is the simple code I was able to re-produce

Comment: @Test <br/>
public void test() throws IOException {<br/>
  <br/>
  InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("test.xls");<br/>
  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is, true);<br/>
  
  HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  
  sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(4, 7, 0, 1));
  
  FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("./new-test.xls");
  
  wb.write(fs);
  
} `code`

Comment: The excel file test.xls has 2 columns starting at row 5 to row 8. The picture (logo) is a png file at the top. If I don't execute setAutoFilter the logo stays. Otherwise the filters are applied and the png file to removed

Comment: @rgettman Apache POI 3.9 solved the issue. The picture is not getting removed any more when I set setAutoFilters on the sheet. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Apache POI 3.9 resolved this issue